# What is the software updater doing compared to e.g. "sudo apt-get update"?

Tags: 14.04, update-manager

Often I have a shell open already and I notice the software updater is telling me there are updates. To save me the time on extra mouse clicks, I want to just update via the shell. But if I just do "sudo apt-get update", the software updater still shows me pending updates and this is also the case even after rebooting the system - if I'm not mistaken.

So, if I want to do the same thing as the software updater in the shell, what commands do I have to call?

sudo apt-get update?
sudo apt-get upgrade?
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade?
All of them?

Comment: see http://superuser.com/questions/602109/software-updater-vs-apt-get-update

Answer (score 1):

`apt-get update` only refreshes the available packages lists. `apt-get upgrade` does the actual upgrade. `apt-get dist-upgrade`, unlike `apt-get upgrade` has the ability to install or delete packages (that's what the GUI call an "intelligent upgrade". Normally, since dependencies aren't supposed to change during a release's lifecycle, for day-to-day upgrades, `apt-get update` followed by `apt-get upgrade` is enough. You should run `apt-get dist-upgrade` only when some packages are held back.

All that (and far more) is explained in apt-get manual page (`man apt-get`).